# Django unique random as a default value

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to check if a value exists in a model when assigning it as a default value? If the assigning value exists (it's not unique), then generate another value. (Read comments):

```
def unique_rand():
    return ... # Generate a random string with 8 characters length
               # It shouldn't exists among other persons
               # If exists then generate another random string


class Person(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, default=unique_rand())
```

Maybe the workaround cannot be inside `unique_rand` but somewhere inside `Person` class.
I don't want override `save` method because I need the `code` before `save`. Also, I don't want to use `uuid` randoms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just test the existence of the generated code in the loop.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def unique_rand():
    while True:
        code = password = User.objects.make_random_password(length=8)
        if not Person.objects.filter(code=code).exists():
            return code

class Person(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True, default=unique_rand)
```

Note that there is no round brackets in the `default=unique_rand` argument.

If you want to limit the number of attempts then change the loop from `while` to `for`:

```
def unique_rand():
    for _ in range(5):
        ...
    raise ValueError('Too many attempts to generate the code')
```

Comment: Note that @catavaran has changed `default=unique_rand()` to `default=unique_rand`. It was made so the `unique_rand()` function would be called every time you create a `Person` object. Otherwise it would be called just once - on model's initialization.

Comment: There must be a race problem! Imagine `p1 = Person();  p2 = Person()` then `p1.code` could be as same as `p2.code` because they've not saved yet. What about this situation ?!

Comment: Then `IntegrityError` exception will be raised.  You can't avoid this anyway.

Comment: @M M: that's an impossibility in your requirements, it seems to me.

Comment: Yes, I think it is impossible. At least as a straightforward solution. The generated codes should be stored somewhere else. BTW, thanks for your help.

Comment: You can create another model with the single unique field to store generated codes.  Then in the `unique_rand()` you can try to save the code in this model and catch `IntegrityError` to retry with the new code. But then you have to take care of the synchronization of these two tables.