# migration trouble with unique random default value in model django

Tags: python, django, model

I want to add a new field to my already existing model called `color`. I want it to be unique and also want it to be randomly selected by default. So what I do is:

```
color = models.CharField(max_length=15, default=random_color, unique=True)
```

My `random_color` looks like this

```
def random_color():
"""
Returns:
    [string] : returns a rgb value in hex string
"""
while True:
    generated_color = f'#{random_hex()}{random_hex()}{random_hex()}'
    if not MyModel.objects.filter(color=generated_color):
        return generated_color
```

I followed a similar logic to what has been provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419477/django-unique-random-as-a-default-value).

Now the problem with this approach is that there is no `color` to begin with to look for.

And I also want my migration to add in a bunch of default random color values to my already existing tables.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be a simpler way to accomplish this, but these steps should work:

1. Add the new `color` field with `null=True` and without the default and the `unique=True`.
2. Run `makemigrations` for your app.
3. Run `makemigrations --empty` to create a custom migration for your app. Add a [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#runpython) operation using your `random_color()` to populate the new column.
4. Alter the `color` field to add the default, unique constraint, and remove the `null=True`.
5. Run `makemigrations` again.

Comment: This is the way to go! I do not know of a simpler way. For a more detailed explanation, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29787853/django-migrations-add-field-with-default-as-function-of-model?rq=2